# Making the elements in the Gridview clickable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have 5 rows in my table say 
(no,name,address,phone,age) 
I'm displaying the values from the sql and displaying no and name in firstpage.aspx via GridView

1.Now what I want is, when I click on any name in the gridview should display the adjacent values (address ,phone ,age)in newpage.aspx page

2.The problem im facing is, I'm not able to make the fields in the gridview clickable.

3.Is it possible to make the elements in the gridivew clickable  or can u guys suggest me another way of making this possible or is there anyother way of retrieving datas from the db other than the gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make columns clickable. It would be easy if you use TemplateFields and ItemTemplates.
For example:

```
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <a href="#" onclick="redirect('<%# Eval("some_ID") %>')"><%# Eval        ("some_Fieldname") %></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField>
    ...
    </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
```

You can use a javascript for redirect such as

```
    function redirect(target)
    {
      window.open('some_url/some_page?id='+target+'','mytarget');
    }
```

In the template field you can use any html tag like DIV or SPAN instead of HREF.

In the target page, you can capture this Id and make necessary coding.

Comment: i  mean i dont want it to be displayed in a table in the second page, i need it to be displayed something like http://i.imgur.com/3JzPXaF.png according to the selected value from the first page

Comment: Yes. It is what I meant. You probably would have a row from where this data comes from and the row is likely to have a key. This key is what you supply to the script and from there as a querystring to another page. You can easily fetch the details once you get the key in the second page and display as you feel like.